# Which term groups "bare", "unfurnished", "semi-furnished", "furnished"?

Tags: terminology

We're building a form and need a category name that has the words listed above as options. Is "furnishings" correct?

Comment: condition? oft used in antiques...

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Doesn't condition have more to do with whether the room/house is damaged, needs repairing, etc? How about just _furnishing_?

Comment: @Phil14; condition just means state. Google says: the state of something, especially with regard to its appearance, quality, or working order.
"the wiring is in good condition"

Comment: I think @Phil14 's answer 'furnishing' (singular) would be the most appropriate and in keeping with a typical apartment or home listing.  "flooring(wood, carpet, or tile)", "heating(forced air, wall-heater, radiator)", "parking(2 cars covered, permit, 2 assigned)" . "furnishings"(plural) would be appropriate if you were going to list the individual items that would be included.  ('bed", "desk, dinette with 4 chairs)

Comment: The individual items to be included would be "bare", "unfurnished", "semi-furnished" and "fully furnished", meaning the full range from a unit that only has concrete floor and unpainted walls with no sanitary facilities up to a unit that has been fully designed and decorated. Would "funishings" still work then and would it be singular or plural?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **level of furnishment** would work.

From OED:

> **furnishment** *noun*
>
> 1. The action of furnishing or supplying; **the state of being furnished or supplied**

Answer (score 1):

Furnishment would not be used commonly, even in the UK.

Furnishings is perfectly acceptable.